# Never getting out of while loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, while-loop, parse-platform

I have a method that needs to wait for another method to finish loading some objects from the datastore. So I'm using a while loop like this:

```
-(void) findAGoodCar {
    [self.indicator startAnimating];

    while(appDelegate.availableCars == nil || [appDelegate.availableCars count] < 1) {
        sleep(0.01);
    }

    // do some stuff
}
```

While this starts working the other process, for loading the cars, has already started.

Now, the indicator never starts animating. The loading of objects never finishes. The loop never ends. Why?

EDIT: This is my loadCars method. It is called from the appDelegate when the app starts, from `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` and is doing the query to Parse.com's cloud asynchronously:

```
+(void) loadCars {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kCarObjectKey];
    [query whereKey:kActiveKey equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:kActiveNumber]];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByPrice = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kPriceKey ascending:YES];
    [query orderBySortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortByPrice, nil]];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            appDelegate.availableCars = objects;
         } else {
            NSLog(@"Error in loadCars %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I think you should use KVO, and get notified when the array is loaded.

Comment: While condition never getting false

Comment: As you have indicated you are using an Indicator so you can stop the indicator once you have successfully loaded a car. I don't think you need a while loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is updated post, because it the real author's problem is not a "infinite loop".

## Working with Parse

Parse provides two ways of getting/putting data to its servers:

- sync
- async

### Sync

Drawbacks of sync method is obvious - it blocks UI thread and user see unresponsive UI.

*Then why was that group of methods inroduced?*

There are some cases in your app's login when you can't continue working without knowing the result. In that case you have to use sync methods.

### Async

Async approach doesn't block UI. But it requires deeper understaning of process.

Of course, you can use such loops:

```
while(appDelegate.availableCars == nil || [appDelegate.availableCars count] < 1) {
    sleep(0.01);
}
```

That approach will give you the result, but you block a UI thread. Using such approach for async operation is bad practive. You should consider using block for handling asynchronyous requests.

## App's architecture

Here is my point of view on app's architecture.
I prefer isolating all the code, working with Parse (and other APIs) into separate classes.
So I make a class, and make it singleton

**ParseClient.h file:**

```
@interface ParseClient : NSObject
// singleton
+ (instancetype) sharedInstance;
@end
```

**ParseClient.m file:**

```
@implementation ParseClient
+ (instancetype) sharedInstance {
    static ParseClient *sharedInstace = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstace = [[ParseClient alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstace;
}
@end
```

So now you have access to parse object in whole app. Now you can add required function to this class. You can add cache (for example, store an array as instance variable) and make your own cache policy.

For example, you can add the following function to ParseClient:

```
- (void) loadCarsWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *objects, NSError *error))completionBlock {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kCarObjectKey];
    [query whereKey:kActiveKey equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:kActiveNumber]];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortByPrice = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:kPriceKey ascending:YES];
    [query orderBySortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortByPrice, nil]];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:completionBlock];
}
```

and call it in anywhere in your app

```
- (void) foo {
    ...
    [[ParseClient sharedInstance] loadCarsWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        // you have array of cars here 
    }];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm actually loading the cars asynchronously. I edited the question with my loadCars method.

Comment: @Eddy I've modified my answer. Why do you have NSArray of cars in AppDelegate?

Comment: @Thanks, Nikita. Well, I'm loading the cars in the appDelegate because I want to get them ahead of the user clicking the button that triggers my loadCars method. And also I'm using the array in other parts of the app, so the delegate seems like a reasonable place to put it. So what are my options? I could see in my controller if the cars are already loaded in the delegate, and if not call my loadCars method from the controller like you suggest. But that doesn't seem like a great design either. So what's the solution?

Comment: @Eddy I will rewrite my post to show my understanding of working with parse

Answer (score 2):

Seems like 'findAGoodCar' is executed on main thread. In that case, you are blocking the main thread of the app. It will block all the UI events.

Answer (score 2):

It is still bad, but i don't see your whole picture. Try this:

```
 while(appDelegate.availableCars == nil || [appDelegate.availableCars count] < 1) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
}
```

This won't block main thread

Comment: It is bad from the point of view of designing. You should not wait for the end of a task in a while loop. It will bring you no good, believe me. You should stick more to the approach proposed by Nikita Took i.e. set piece of code to be performed by the end of operation.

Comment: but i don't mind if you upvote my answer since it helped you locally and let you know how to make a pause without blocking main thread

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loading cars in the same thread.
Try:

```
while(0 == appDelegate.availableCars.count) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```